# Check for nil result in ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a few places in a model that does stuff like

```
  def ServerInfo.starttime(param)
    find(:all, :conditions => "name ='#{param}_started'", :select => "date").first.date.to_datetime
  end
```

Now, for reasons not relevant to the question, it can happen that this particular row is not in the database at all and the code above fails with `` NoMethodError (undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass): ``. My current fix is

```
    res = find(:all, :conditions => "name ='#{param}_started'", :select => "date")
    check_time = res.first.nil? ? 0 : res.first.date.to_datetime
```

This works find, but I feel it's not right to sprinkle that code all over the place. Is there some more ruby-ish / rail-ish way to prevent dereferencing nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to avoid the NoMethodError for nil, you should define a `begin` `rescue` block,

```
def ServerInfo.starttime(param)
  begin
    find(:all, :conditions => "foo").first.date.to_datetime
  rescue
    0
  end
end
```

I also like the Rails [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method:

```
find(:all, :conditions => "foo").first.try(:date).try(:to_datetime) || 0
```

Comment: I'd use the try method, it's very useful.

Comment: Sweet, didn't know about Rails `try`. That's what I went with, for brevity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is cleaner:

```
check_time = res.first.date.to_datetime if res.first
```

btw, don't use:

```
:conditions => "name ='#{param}_started'" # SQL injection vulnerability.
```

use this one instead:

```
:conditions => ["name = ?", "#{param}_started"] # This is safer. Pure clean Ruby
```

it's safer

Answer (score 0):

You may also define a scope. For instance in a Rails3 app you should try:

In your ServerInfo.rb model:

```
scope :starttime, lambda{|param|
  if self.has_attribute?(param+'_started')
    where("name = ?", param+'_started' ).select('date')
  else
    false
  end
}
```

// Remember to never put your params directly in your sql query, that is bad practice since you risk some sql injection //

Then in a controller:

```
res = ServerInfo.starttime('a_param')
check_time = res.first.date.to_datetime if res
```

I didn't try that code, then you may need to adapt it to your need (or to your Rails2 app)